# Why doesn't the range of $f(x) = |x|$ include $0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my pre-calc book they show the range of $f(x) = |x$| as $[0,\infty)$.  But why is this not inclusive of zero $(0,\infty)$?  We have two cases with $f(x) = |x|$.  They are $x < 0$ and $x\ge  0$.  I get with $x < 0$ zero isn't included because x never equals 0 but for $x \ge 0$, $x$ can equal zero.  And clearly $|0| = 0$ so what am I missing?

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ means that zero **is** included

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5ddhgaqqbv

Comment: $0$ is in the range, as you state. The description you give happens not to use the closed left half line in specifying the function, but it could.

Comment: See that $(0, 0)$ _does_ lie on the equation $y=|x|$. I think you messed up your terms as 57Jimmy points out.

Comment: ok, now I feel stupid.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

$$[0, \infty) = \{ x | x \ge 0\}$$

It is included in the range due to $f(0)=0$.

In contrast $$(0, \infty) = \{ x | x > 0\}$$ and hence

$$(0, \infty) \subset [0,\infty)$$

and the two sets differ by the element $0$.

Square braces include the boundary while round braces exclude the boundary.